# Broadcast Receiver with three activity

Tags: android

i have three activities all are register with same broadcast receiver. which activity will get first broadcast receiver? Any source code snippet will be helpful in explanation

Comment: Firstly, work on [accepting more answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Second, this question needs a lot of elaboration before it will get any real answers; try to rethink your question and be as specific as possible.

Comment: Dear elaborate your doubt more clearly...

Answer (score 1):

broadcastreceiver will receiver normal broadcast randomly.
If you want your broadcastreceivers receive broadcast sequentially, please use orderedbroadcast providered by AndroidSDK.
google it.

Comment: which activity will receive broadcast first among all the activities ?

Comment: God knows...I think it really depends. You can have a test. When one received the broadcast, print out the time. Test more than one time to come to the conclusion.